# Get object data in foreach

Tags: php, object

I'm trying to get some data from my object. My problem is that I would like it to be done in a foreach loop like this:

```
@foreach($event_types as $event_type_key => $event_type_val)

  echo $data->Type.''.$event_type_key;

@endforeach
```

But it does not work, I get the error: Undefined property: stdClass::$Type.

In my object I have data like Type1, Type2, Type3...

And it works if I change the code to:

```
@foreach($event_types as $event_type_key => $event_type_val)

  echo $data->Type1;

@endforeach
```

But I would like the type count to change with the value from the $event_types array.

Can somebody see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I dynamically write a PHP object property name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571197/how-do-i-dynamically-write-a-php-object-property-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply

```
@foreach($event_types as $event_type_key => $event_type_val)

  echo $data->{'Type' . $event_type_key};

@endforeach
```

Comment: You should write `'Type'.$event_type_key` or PHP will think it is a constant.

Answer (score 0):

You want to dynamically write a PHP object property.

You do it thus:

```
 $key = "Type1";
 $data->$key;
```

In your case:

```
foreach($event_types as $event_type_key => $event_type_val):
  $k = 'Type'.$event_type_key;
  echo $data->$k;
endforeach
```

You should not use `@` to suppress errors. It hides bugs.