# Using a variable to define $this-> variable - PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to learn PHP classes and I am stuck on something that I think should work..

I am trying to be clever with the code rather than have lots of if statements.

Firstly, the $queryResult data contains the following

```
POSITION     COUNT
L1           5
L2           24
L3           87
```

**Here is the Class -**

```
class WIPData 
   {
    public $queryResult;
    public $L1 = 0;
    public $L2 = 0;
    public $L3 = 0; 


    function WIPData($results)
    {

        $queryResult = $results;

        while ($values = CDB::GetAssoc($queryResult)) {
       if ($queryResult)
       {
           $rPos = $values['POSITION'];
           $this->$rPos = $values['COUNT'];

//       if ($values['POSITION'] == "L1")
//       {
//           $this->L1 = $values['COUNT'];
//       }
//       if ($values['POSITION'] == "L2")
//       {
//           $this->L2= $values['COUNT'];
//       }
//       if ($values['POSITION'] == "L3")
//       {
//           $this->L3= $values['COUNT'];
//       }
          }
}


    }

}
```

As you can see the commented out if statement is quite a bit of code, and also when there are more positions, this will be even bigger..

So I thought I would try to be clever and do the

```
$rPos = $values['POSITION'];  
  $this->$rPos = $values['COUNT'];
```

The idea is that 'POSITION' will always be one of the variable names eg, L1, L2, L3, so really the code in php's eyes would be

```
$this->L1 = $values['COUNT'];
```

But, for some reason, the variables do not get populated.

Am I doing something impossible here?

Any advice would be really helpful!

Comment: What do you mean 'by doesn't work at all'?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571197/how-do-i-dynamically-write-a-php-object-property-name

Comment: Thanks @MilanG - The question you referenced solved my problem!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
class WIPData {
    public $queryResult;
    public $L1 = 0;
    public $L2 = 0;
    public $L3 = 0; 

    function WIPData($results) {
        $this->queryResult = $results;

        if (!empty($this->queryResult)) {
            while ($values = CDB::GetAssoc($this->queryResult)) {
                  $this->{$rPos} = $values['POSITION'];
                  $this->{$rPos} = $values['COUNT'];
            }
        }
    }
}
```