# Create a dynamic table in laravel blade

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm having a problem in creating table dynamically.

Basically I'm fetching data from database by following statement:

```
$data = User::all();
```

After that I have fetched attributes name of database table by following statement:

```
$columns = DB::getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing('users');
```

After that $data and `$columns` is sent to View by following statement:

```
return view('framework/list', compact('data', 'columns'));
```

In my view i.e list.blade.php two foreach loops are used to create `<tr>` and `<td>` just like this:

```
@foreach($data as $singleUser)
<tr>
    @foreach($columns as $cols)
    <td>

        {{$singleUser->$cols}}
        {{Blade::compileString('"'.'$singleUser->'."$cols".'"')}}
                                     
    </td>
    @endforeach
</tr>
@endforeach
```

But I get an exception, instead of printing values (two statements are used to print values but both of them giving same exception)

> (3/3) ErrorException
>
> Trying to get property of non-object (View: /home/srmd/biniHR/resources/views/layouts/key.blade.php) (View: /home/srmd/resources/views/layouts/key.blade.php)

Comment: Try: `return view('framework/list')->with('data' => $data)->with('coloumns' => $coloumns);`

Comment: share one element of `$data` and `$coloumns` ?

Comment: @Troyer same issue

Comment: @user2486 nope i want to pass both objects to view and against that objects <tr> and <td> should be created.

Comment: I am share with us, paste output in your question ?

Comment: Its already Pasted,i.e (3/3)ErrorException.......

Answer (score 3):

For a dynamic call you have to use: `{{$singleUser->{$cols}}}`

> This "enclose with braces" trick is useful in PHP whenever there is
>   ambiguity due to variable variables.

[How do I dynamically write a PHP object property name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571197/how-do-i-dynamically-write-a-php-object-property-name)

Instead of getting the database values you can transform your userobject to an array and iterate over it:

```
@foreach($data as $singleUser)
<tr>
    @foreach($singleUser->toArray() as $key => $value)
    <td>
        Key {{ $key }}
        Value {{ $value }}
        Value {{ $singleUser->toArray()[$key] }} //equal to first try
        Value {{ $singleUser->{$key} }} // not sure if it works, but it should
    </td>
    @endforeach
</tr>
@endforeach
```