# PHP - Convert array in class variables

Tags: php

How can I convert array (assoc or seq) into class variables:

I have this array

```
[
    "uuidtype"=>4,
    "data"=>[
        "name"=>"Arthur",
        "age"=>"unknown"
    ]
]
```

I have this class:

```
class Example{
    public static function ___g($var_name, $val){
        // static $$varname = $val; Doesn't work
        // self::${(string)$varname} = $val; Doesn't work
    }
}
```

I want this:

```
class Example{
    public static $uuidtype = 4;
    public static $data;

    ...
}
```

Comment: my vote would be to define a basic class and use magic [__get/__call](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) methods, at which point this array would become a property of this class instance, and your __get/__call methods would interact with the array data and act accordingly

Comment: Also, tell us about the problem you're trying to solve and tell us _why_ you think this is the solution to your problem?

Comment: Class properties are for defining static values, not runtime data. Runtime data would be in the object itself, so either in a method, or specifically get/set methods, or the constructor - whichever makes sense for what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an Array and then cast it as object, so:

```
$arr = [
    "uuidtype"=>4,
    "data"=>[
        "name"=>"Arthur",
        "age"=>"unknown"
    ]
]

$as_class = (object) $arr;

echo $as_class->uuidtype; //Works ;)
```

I am not sure about performance, but works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Php __get magic method. It allows dynamically creating object properties. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get. A similar question was asked on: [How do I dynamically write a PHP object property name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571197/how-do-i-dynamically-write-a-php-object-property-name)