# Laravel Blade : Accessing object properties dynamically

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Im trying to access a property of an object by a dynamic property name within Laravel Blade file. Im getting the following error

> ErrorException (E_ERROR) Object of class stdClass could not be
>   converted to string (View:
>   /Users/kusal/Sites/laravel/masterdata/MD.UI/views/update.blade.php)

Code:

```
{{ $data->$control->value_column }}
```

I want to access the $control->value_column of $data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I dynamically write a PHP object property name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571197/how-do-i-dynamically-write-a-php-object-property-name)

Comment: This is relevant to Laravel's templating engine - Blade

Comment: No it isn't, it's just PHP syntax. `{{ $variable }}` gets parsed to `<?php echo e($variable); ?>`. Blade is just an easier to read version.

Comment: Could not find above quoted answer by the error message "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string". Anyway Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
echo $data->{$control->value_column};
```