# How can we pass array into object in php

Tags: php

```
class A {
  public $a;
  public $b;

  function f1 () {
     // Code
  }
}

$obj = new A();

$arr = array ("a" => 1, "b" => 2);

foreach ($arr as $name => $value) {
  $obj->$name = $value;
}

return $obj;
```

I am not able to understand `foreach` section. How can we pass array as object and fetch that data as array?

Comment: Hi, this might help [How foreach works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-does-php-foreach-actually-work)

Comment: i know about foreach, but question is how can we store value for variable and returning that as object and that object behave as array?

Comment: "Pass array as object" where?

Comment: It's not a very good example of [variable variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571197/how-do-i-dynamically-write-a-php-object-property-name), it's using `$arr` (an array) to set the properties of `$obj` (an object) and returning the object.

Comment: return $obj;

when we return $obj; it passes a array right? if i am wrong just explain what it passes.

Comment: `$obj` is an __object__ of class A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can please check below code.

```
class A {
  public $a;
  public $b;

  function f1 () {
     // Code
  }
}

$obj = new A();
$arr = array ("a" => 1, "b" => 2);
foreach ($arr as $name => $value) {
  $obj->$name = $value;
}

return $obj;
// This return obj output is :-
A Object
(
    [a] => 1
    [b] => 2
)
```

Update your code with below code your will get array.

```
return (array)$obj;
//Output 

Array
(
    [a] => 1
    [b] => 2
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Explanation of your foreach loop:

1. Each loop you get key name of array and value of array element
2. Than you set $obj property here $obj->$name = $value;
3. $name is replaced with array key name therefore it looks like $obj->a = $value;

To pass array to object, use magic setter method:

```
class A {
  public $a;
  public $b;

  public function __set($property, $value) {
    if (property_exists($this, $property)) {
      $this->$property = $value;
    }

    return $this;
  }
}

$obj = new A();

$arr = array ("a" => 1, "b" => 2);

foreach ($arr as $name => $value) {
  $obj->__set($name, $value);
}
```

All of the object are as array automatically, so to fetch it back as array, you can loop object directly:

```
foreach ($obj as $key => $value) {
  print "$key => $value\n";
}
```

To get directly full array from object you can make another method which will do this for you:

```
public function getAsArray() {
   $arr = array();
   foreach ($this as $key => $value) {
       $arr[$key] = $value;
   }

   return $arr;
}
```

Comment: my question was can we pass array into object and we can fetch that object as array despite of loop and methods

Comment: just want to understand this code, as i was not able to understand

Comment: Edited answer with explanation of your foreach loop.

Comment: If it helped you, please set my answer as correct one. Thank you!