# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in... when upgrading to php 7.0

Tags: php, function, error-handling, syntax-error

I am updating my sites php ver to 7.0 When I do so it throws this error on a theme we have installed that no longer is technically supported. This is the code that it references the error on.

```
   /**
    * Iterate over all template elements and if a rendering method for that element exists
    * call that method. Pass the current element so the rendering class knows which values to use
    */
    function generate_html()
    {   
        foreach($this->template_elements as $element)
        {
            if(method_exists($this, $element['dynamic']))
            {           
                if(isset($element['saved_value']))
                {
                    $this->dynamic_counter ++;
                    $this->final_output[] = $this->$element['dynamic']({$element);
                }
            }       
            $this->current_index ++;
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have a solution to this error on php 7.0?

Comment: Well, what *is* `$this->$element['dynamic']`? You may have to group this expression differently as `$this->{$element['dynamic']}(...)`.

Comment: I guess you *may* be stumbling across this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12571247/476